# A type guard on literal union types

Tags: typescript

I have two types in TypeScript:

```
type PublicMethods = 'Time' | 'Assets' | 'AssetPairs' ;
type PrivateMethods = 'Balance' | 'TradeBalance';
```

I would like to use the same `api` function to handle these types, but the behaviour is different for each. Something along the lines of:

```
public api = (method: PublicMethods | PrivateMethods, params: any) => {

  // ...how do I create a type guard here?
  if(method instanceof PublicMethods) { //  Doesn't like this!
    // ...
  }

}
```

I also tried overloading the function, like this:

```
public api(method: PublicMethods | PrivateMethods, params: any, callback: Function);

public api(method: PublicMethods, params: any, callback: Function) {
   // ...implementation
}

public api(method: PrivateMethods, params: any, callback: Function) {
   // ...implementation
}
```

Didn't like that either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your types based on a constant array:

```
const PublicMethods = ['Time', 'Assets', 'AssetPairs'] as const;
const PrivateMethods = ['Balance', 'TradeBalance'] as const;

type PublicMethods = typeof PublicMethods[number];
type PrivateMethods = typeof PrivateMethods[number];
```

You'll now be able to use the name `PublicMethods` as *both* a type and a *variable* that refers to the union of strings and array, respectively. With this, you can create a user-defined type guard using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isPublicMethod(value: string): value is PublicMethods {
    // some sort of assertion is needed because
    // it will error that type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Time" | "Assets" | "AssetPairs"'
    return PublicMethods.includes(value as any);
}
```

This allows you to narrow the value to `PublicMethods`, the type, by checking if `PublicMethods`, the array, includes `value`:

```
function doStuff(method: PrivateMethods | PublicMethods) {
    if (isPublicMethod(method)) {
        method
        // ^? PublicMethods
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqeLYm)

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks! Although I modified the signature to be `isPublicMethod(value: PublicMethods | PrivateMethods)`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a type guard like this:

```
const isPublicMethod = (value: any): value is PublicMethod => {
  return ['Time', 'Assets', 'AssetPairs'].includes(value);
};
```

and then use it in your API integration function:

```
public api = (method: PublicMethods | PrivateMethods, params: any) => {
  if(isPublicMethod(method)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Warning! Be careful, since TS will not throw if `PublicMethod` type is updated and type guard is not.

To handle this better, use the following approach:

```
const PUBLIC_METHODS = ['Time', 'Assets', 'AssetPairs'] as const;

type PublicMethod = typeof PUBLIC_METHODS[number];

const isPublicMethod = (value: any): value is PublicMethod => {
  return PUBLIC_METHODS.includes(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I had already accepted the answer by @vera. I augmented the signature of the function to be `isPublicMethod(value: PublicMethods | PrivateMethods)`

Comment: Why have you updated the type? Why should `isPublicMethod` be aware of `PrivateMethods` at all? In any case, type guards' argument can be anything and might be used anywhere, that's why it should be `unknown` but then with some conditions it becomes "known". In some cases typescript complains about `unknown` (as in current case), then you can use `any`.